# JavaScript crash on IE8 and IE9-CompabilityMode: SCRIPT601: Unknown runtime error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, runtime-error

Page works fine on Chrome, IE9, FF, but gives me this error on IE8 and IE9-compabilitymode: SCRIPT601: Unknown runtime error with a reference to this bit of javascript:

```
function Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_updatePanel(updatePanelElement, rendering) {
        for (var updatePanelID in this._scriptDisposes) {
            if (this._elementContains(updatePanelElement, document.getElementById(updatePanelID))) {
                var disposeScripts = this._scriptDisposes[updatePanelID];
                for (var i = 0, l = disposeScripts.length; i < l; i++) {
                    eval(disposeScripts[i]);
                }
                delete this._scriptDisposes[updatePanelID];
            }
        }
        this._destroyTree(updatePanelElement);
        updatePanelElement.innerHTML = rendering; //this is where it crashes
    }
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: If you remove all but `updatePanelElement.innerHTML = rendering;` does it still happen? If so whats in `rendering`

Comment: More important, what sort of element is "updatePanelElement"?  If you try to use "innerHTML" on an element that IE doesn't think can have any HTML in it (like a `<style>` element), you get that "unknown error" exception.

Comment: It seems as if updatePanelElement is an ASP Update Panel element. What I mean is, this javascript code is not written in the application. I've still had no progress with this whatsoever, trying to recreate the problem with a dummy page with no success so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occured because of a misplaced

paragraph. I found [this](http://blog.rakeshpai.me/2007/02/ies-unknown-runtime-error-when-using.html) link that describes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can resolve this issue by using any one of the 2 solutions as below:

**First Solution:**

DOCTYPE might be missed in the html which need to be placed as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

If this solution did not worked , we can try second solution.

**Second Solution:**

I replaced

document.getElementById('divHTML').innerHTML = HTMLData;

with

jQuery('#divHTML').html(HTMLData);

Here HTMLData is the variable that holds the html data we want to place in divHTML.